# Payment specific coupon code for woocommerce (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment, coupon

In woocommerce (for wordpress) I would like to restrict coupon usage to one payment option. What is the best way to go around it?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-auto-added-coupons/

Comment: You can use the plugin